# CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation cannot be executed

Tags: clgeocoder

everything is OK when I'm using 'MKReverseGeocoder' to get the address from coordination, such as the following source code:

```
    MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc]
                                   initWithCoordinate:self.currentLocation.coordinate];
    geocoder.delegate = self;

    [geocoder start];

}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
    NSLog(@"%@", placemark);
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

but, when I use 'CLGeocoder' like this:

```
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Received placemarks: %@", placemarks);
}];
```

I get nothing, and I guess the code has not been executed at all when I debug it because I didn't find any information on the output console.

anyone can tell me what's wrong?? thank you.

Comment: I am having the same problem, i guess it has something to do with threading.

Comment: How did you create your CLGeocoder? Are you sure your `geocoder` instance is not nil? Set a breakpoint on your `reverseGeocodeLocation:` line and determine whether or not that is called.